# capture everything but specific regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm having some trouble trying to implement some regex. I need to capture everything except one specific operator. So this is the format essentially:

fraction operator fraction

This is the current regex:

```
([ \t]*-?[0-9]+[ \t]*/[ \t]*-?[0-9]+[ \t]*)
```

Right now, it's capturing both fractions, but I need it to just get operator. So for example, if I entered:

```
-12/43 - 3/-5
```

It would capture `-12/43` and `3/-5`. I need it to capture everything but that; I need it to capture the operator in the middle.

I've tried searching for a while, but I get different answers detailing how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: are you thinking of `^` ?

Comment: Always only 2 "values" separated by an operator ? if not what are the other variations ?

Answer (score 0):

A fairly simple way to do what you are asking for is to just replace your fractions with `""` - then whatever you have left is the operator.

```
Pattern fraction = Pattern.compile("\\s*-?\\d+\\s*/\\s*-?\\d+\\s*");
Matcher matcher = fraction.match(myExpression);
String operator = matcher.replaceAll("").trim();
```

The `operator` variable is now the original expression with all substrings matching the fraction pattern removed.

Note that I've used the predefined character classes for whitespace and digits.

Although this should work I don't recommend this approach. Assuming you will want to do something with the expression (like evaluate it) you are much better off using a proper lexical & semantic analysis technique. There are third party libraries (e.g. [JFlex](http://jflex.de/)) that can do the job with pretty minimal effort and a lot more flexibility.

Comment: Isn't `String.replaceAll` better to use in this case?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Personal preference but I tend to make my patterns `static` `final` like any other constants rather than embedding in the statement. But you're probably correct that it would have made the answer a bit simpler.

Comment: I tried your method and it worked except one part. I tried an expressions like this: 1/2-1/2. It should be 1/2 minus 1/2, but instead picks it up as 1/2 (negative)1/2. This "1/2- 1/2" would work but "1/2     -1/2" will not.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a capturing group:

```
/(?:\s*-?\d+\s*\/\s*-?\d+)\s*([*/+-])\s*(?:\s*-?\d+\s*\/\s*-?\d+)/ig
```

I'll explain what's happening here. We have three capture groups: 2 which are non-capturing groups `(?:.*)` and one capturing group `(.*)`. The non-capturing groups are surrounding the fractions that you're ignoring while the capturing group is surrounding the operator that you are looking for `[*/+-]`. Now you can get the operator with:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:\\s*-?\\d+\\s*\\/\\s*-?\\d+)\\s*([*/+-])\\s*(?:\\s*-?\\d+\\s*\\/\\s*-?\\d+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.match(whatAreWeMatching);
String operator = matcher.group(1); // returns "-" with the example you gave
```

Note that I've also included a lot of checks for whitespace `\s*` so that you can freely put spaces between any operator. Without checking for whitespace, the regex would look a lot smaller but would not account for things like `-21 / 12 + 14 / -5`. If you're confident that your input will only have the structure you have shown us, you could use:

```
/(?:-?\d+\/-?\d+) ([*/+-]) (?:-?\d+\/-?\d+)/ig
```

(Just remember to add an extra backslash to all backslashes before putting this in a string.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have always inputs of this structures: `values separated by single operators`, then I simply appended to your expression an alternation branch to grab that operator:

`|(\S)` or `|([+-*/])` if you already know what those operators should be.

Which gives:

```
([ \t]*-?[0-9]+[ \t]*/[ \t]*-?[0-9]+[ \t]*)|(\S)
```

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/wP8pX9/1)

**Note:** OFC you should escape slaches in your code accordingly !!